# Jquery UI tabs - Selected tab smaller line-height -> last tab breaks design

Tags: css, jquery-ui, firefox, jquery-ui-tabs

I am having a css problem with my jQuery UI tabs. I want to show which tab is selected by changing the height of the tab link:[image: Selected tab is marked by its size]

I do this by changing the line-height of the anchor:

```
.ui-state-active a,
.ui-state-active a:link,
.ui-state-active a:visited {
  line-height: 10px;
}
```

Unfortunately this breaks the layout whenever you select the last tab on the row:

[image: broken layout]

When I tried to solve this by adding a margin to the li element:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

The problem is fixed when the last element is selected, but now all other tabs break the layout when selected:

[image: all tabs break layout when selected]

So how to solve this? Issue was seen in firefox, not a 100% sure but it seems Chrome is unaffected.

Here a minimum example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gkt6bco6/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused because all the elements float left. If you "clear:left" the element that wraps around, the issue goes away. Unfortunately, it's hard to say  clear: left of the element after the selected one whenever the selected one is the last on a line in CSS.

I found that if you take out the float and change display to inline-block, the issue goes away.

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```